# Cutting off local Lipschitz gives global Lipschitz

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification, lipschitz-functions, stochastic-differential-equations

I came across this problem in a proof of an existence result for stochastic differential equations with locally Lipschitz coefficients.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfies the following: for any $r>0$ and any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $|x|<r$, $|y|<r$,
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C_r |x-y|,
$$
holds, where the constant $C_r>0$ depends on $r$.

Now, take $\varphi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $0\leq \varphi\leq 1$ and
$\varphi(t)=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{if } t\leq 1\\
0&\text{if } t\geq 2
\end{cases}
$. Let
$$
f_R(x):=f(x)\phi(|x|-R).
$$
Now the claim is for any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^d$, the global Lipschitz condition
$$
|f_R(x)-f_R(y)|\leq C |x-y|,
$$
holds.

---

Here is my proof:

**Case I:** For $|x|\leq R+2$, and $|y|\leq R+2$, first note that we have
$$
|f(y)|\leq |f(0)|+C_{R+2}|y|\leq |f(0)|+C_{R+2}(R+2)=:C'_R<\infty,
$$
where $|f(0)|<\infty$ follows from $f$ being continuous on any closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Hence, it follows
\begin{align}
|f_R(x)-f_R(y)|&\leq |\phi(|x|-R)||f(x)-f(y)|+|f(y)||\phi(|x|-R)-\phi(|y|-R)|\\
&\leq \max_{\mathbb{R}^d}|\phi|C_{R+2}|x-y|+C'_R\, C_\phi |x-y|,
\end{align}
where in the last step we used $\phi$ being global Lipschitz (as it is smooth and compactly supported).

**Case II:** For $|x|\geq R+2$ and $|y|\geq R+2$, we have
$$
|f_R(x)-f_R(y)|=0\leq |x-y|.
$$

Thus, using the argument in the accepted answer and comment of [A step in proof of existence for SDE: handling locally Lipschitz function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050312/a-step-in-proof-of-existence-for-sde-handling-locally-lipschitz-function?noredirect=1&lq=1), we conclude that for $R>0$ fixed, $f_R$ is globally Lipschitz.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you expand the definition of $f_R$ using the definition of $\phi$?

Comment: Your construction seems to mix several approaches of "pacifying" the vector field. It should be $\phi(|x|/R)$ or $\phi(t)=1$ for $t<0$ and $\phi(t)=0$ for $t>1$ to make sense of a windowing of the vector field..

Comment: Consider that $\phi$ itself is Lipschitz and can be selected to have a Lipschitz constant $2$ (or smaller).

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ah ok, I guess the original $\phi$ would have worked but with an unnecessarily tedious argument. Using $\phi$ itself is Lipschitz worked with your hint in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4050312/a-step-in-proof-of-existence-for-sde-handling-locally-lipschitz-function?noredirect=1&lq=1. What you wrote is basically an answer, so I have updated my question instead of posting it as an answer. Thank you!