# A step in proof of existence for SDE: handling locally Lipschitz function

Tags: calculus, analysis, lipschitz-functions, stochastic-differential-equations

On page 56 of [Mao's SDE book](https://www.elsevier.com/books/stochastic-differential-equations-and-applications/mao/978-1-904275-34-3), the author considers an existence result for SDE under the local Lipschitz assumption:
[image]

Here $a\bigvee b:=\max\{a,b\}$.
What he does is to reduce the argument to the global Lipschitz case by considering

$$
f_{n}(x, t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
f(x, t) & \text { if }|x| \leq n \\
f(n x /|x|, t) & \text { if }|x|>n,
\end{array}\right.
$$
also the same for $g$. It is claimed that $f_n$ and $g_n$ satisfies the global Lipschitz and linear growth condition, but I do not see how.

Let us omit $t$. For $|x|\leq n$ and $|y|\leq n$, this is clear, and for $|x|>n$ and $|y|>n$, we have
\begin{align}
|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|&=|f(nx/|x|)-f(ny/|y|)|\leq \sqrt{K_n} |nx/|x|-ny/|y||\\
&=\sqrt{K_n}\, n|x/|x|-y/|y||\leq 2n\, \sqrt{K_n} |x-y|,
\end{align}
where in the last inequality, $|x|,|y|\geq 1\implies |x/|x|-y/|y||\leq 2|x-y|$ is used; cf. [$\left|\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{y}{|y|}\right|\leq |x-y|$, for $|x|, |y|\geq 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1960799/left-fracxx-fracyy-right-leq-x-y-for-x-y-geq-1).

But I do not see how to show the global Lipschitz continuity for other cases; when, WOLG, we have $|x|\leq n$ and $|y|>n$.

A related question is [Cutting off local Lipschitz gives global Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049889/cutting-off-local-lipschitz-gives-global-lipschitz), which is on another way of cooking up a function like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have points on a line, then you can apply the triangle identity to get
$$
|f_n(x_M)-f_n(x_0)|\le\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}|f_n(x_{k+1})-f_n(x_k)|\le L\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}| x_{k+1} - x_k |=L|x_m-x_0|
$$
if all the parts satisfy the Lipschitz condition. Thus you do not need to consider mixed cases as you can take the inner points on the sphere $|x_k|=n$ so that the segments are either completely outside or completely inside.

---

Note that the link for the outside inequaltity was for $|x|\land|y|>1$. Here you have $|x|\land|y|>n$, so that the inequality scales as
$$
|\hat y-\hat x|=\frac{\Bigl||x|\,y-|y|\,x\Bigr|}{|x|\,|y|}
\le\frac{|x|\,|y-x|+\Bigl|(|y|-|x|)\,x\Bigr|}{|x|\,|y|}
=2\frac{|y-x|}{|y|}\le\frac2n|y-x|.
$$

---

This above inequality is true for all vector norms. Specifically for the Euclidean norm one can use Euclidean geometry to get
$$
|\hat y-\hat x|=2d = \frac2{|x|+|y|}\left( |x| d + |y|d\right)\le\frac{2}{|x|+|y|}(|y-z|+|z-x|)=\frac{2}{|x|+|y|}(|y-x|)
$$
where $z$ is the intersection point of the angle bisector of the rays through $x$ and $y$ and the segment $[x,y]$, see the sketch below

[image]

Along these lines more directly
$$
|\hat y-\hat x|
=\frac{\Bigl|y-x+|x|\hat y-|y|\hat x\Bigr|}{|x|+|y|}
\le\frac{\Bigl|y-x\Bigr|+\Bigl||x|\hat y-|y|\hat x\Bigr|}{|x|+|y|}
=\frac{2|y-x|}{|x|+|y|}
$$
as $|x|\hat y-|y|\hat x$ is the reflection of $y-x$ on the angle bisector between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess you meant the following. If $|x|\leq n$ and $|y|>n$, we take a point $z=ax+(1-a)y$, $a\in [0,1]$ such that $|z|=n$, so that
\begin{align}
|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|&\leq |f_n(x)-f_n(z)|+|f_n(z)-f_n(y)|\\
&\leq 2\sqrt{K_n}|x-z|+n\frac2n \sqrt{K_n}|z-y|\\
&=\sqrt{K_n}|(1-a)x-(1-a)y|+2\sqrt{K_n}|ax-ay|\leq 3\sqrt{K_n}|x-y|,
\end{align}
where I used your sharper bound on $|z/|z|-y/|y||$ for $|z|,|y|\geq n$.

Comment: Yes, that. But the last factor only needs to be $2$, $(1-a)+2a=1+a\le 2$.

Comment: Ah ok oops I see, smaller, better, of course. Thank you!

Comment: One can get rid completely of that factor, but only as this is in the 2-norm so that orthogonal projection applies and lengths are additive along a line.

Comment: By that 2-norm is important you meant for the (orthogonal) projection I guess? (The length being additive along the line should hold for any norm as, from $1-a,a\geq0$,
$$|x-z|+|z-y|=
|(1-a)x-(1-a)y|+|ax-ay|=(1-a)|x-y|+a|x-y|=|x-y|
$$)

Comment: On second thought, the main fact that is not present in the counter-examples is that projection leads to proportional/similar triangles, going to lines parallel to $[\hat x\hat y]$ does not give segments that are shorter than the corresponding ones on $[xy]$, there is no Pythagoras.